# Phaser3 - Music broken when starting a new scene

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'm super new to Phaser. I have a main platformer scene which plays a music. Everything was fine until I tried to add a start menu to the game. Here is relevant code of the menu:

```js
public create(): void {
    super.create();

    this.newGameText = this.add
        .text(+this.game.config.width / 2, +this.game.config.height / 2 - 72, "New game", { fontSize: "72px", color: "#fff" })
        .setOrigin(0.5, 0.5)
        .setInteractive();

    this.exitGameText = this.add
        .text(+this.game.config.width / 2, +this.game.config.height / 2 + 72, "Exit game", { fontSize: "72px", color: "#fff" })
        .setOrigin(0.5, 0.5)
        .setInteractive();

    this.music = this.sound.add(Keys.Musics.MainMenu, { loop: true });

    this.music.play();
}

public update(time: number, delta: number): void {
    super.update(time, delta);

    this.newGameText.on(Keys.MouseEvents.PointerDown, () => this.startGame());
    this.exitGameText.on(Keys.MouseEvents.PointerDown, () => this.exitGame());
}

private startGame(): void {
    this.scene.start(Keys.Scenes.Game);
}

private exitGame(): void {
    this.game.destroy(true, true);
}
```

The game scene start playing its own music inside the `create` function, like this:

```js
this.sound.play(Keys.Musics.Level1, {
    loop: true,
    volume: 0.3,
});
```

When I click on "New game", the game scene loads but the sound is aweful, I don't know how to describe it, but something wrong is going on.

If, inside the `startGame()` funciton of the main menu scene, I add `this.music.destroy()`, the next scene plays normally but I have the following error:

> phaser.js:107083 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'disconnect')
> at WebAudioSound.destroy (phaser.js:107083:1)

And here is the source code where it happens:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Sources can be found [here](https://github.com/Robouste/platformer).

Edit: if I remove the music from the main menu, the problem still persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is moving the two eventlistener hooks into the `create` function *(setup should always be done in the `create` function[or in some cases in the `init`])*. Just move two lines into the `create` function:

```
public create(): void {
    ...
    this.newGameText.on(Keys.MouseEvents.PointerDown, () => this.startGame());
    this.exitGameText.on(Keys.MouseEvents.PointerDown, () => this.exitGame());
}
```

the `create` function will only be called "once", and that should be enough.

> *Checkout this unofficial [flow chart of the phaser -game lifeCycle](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/scene/#flow-chart)*
> ***btw.:** the `update` function is called 60 times pre second.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out why.

`this.newGameText.on(Keys.MouseEvents.PointerDown, () => this.startGame());`

this is called ~100 times, so it's starting 100 scenes...

Here is how I fixed it:

```js
private startGame(): void {
    if (!this.startingScene) {
        this.startingScene = true;
        this.music.stop();
        this.scene.start(Keys.Scenes.Game);
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way?